# How to remove a item and delete data from sqlite and can restore in recyclerview?

Tags: android

i want to remove a item in recyclerview and delete from sqlite, but if "undo" i do not know solve this problem with a good way.
this is my code

```
            final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            final thingsModel thing = adapter.getItem(position);
            mList.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,R.string.back,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mList.add(position,thing);
                            adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    storeThingDAO.insertThing(sqLiteDatabase,thing);
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                    }).show();
            if (!mList.contains(thing)){
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        storeThingDAO.deleteThing(sqLiteDatabase,thing.getKey());
                    }
                }).start();
            }
```

this is the way `onSwiped`, i want to find a better way to solve my problem.

Comment: Have an 'active' column in your DB.  Delete doesn't delete it just sets active=false.  If undo then set it to true again.

Comment: Thanks, make a try

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, while deleting maintain *history* somewhere till `Snackbar` is visible then remove it. History should have whole object which you need to delete, row number at which it is being displayed. Once pressed, insert that data at exactly same position and notify `RecyclerView`